# How do I conditionally return from a Mono within a WebFilter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Not sure I'm asking this right so here's an example of what I want to do (in imperative style with blocking)

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
  Mono<MyThing> myThingMono = getMyThingMono();
  // I Know this is not right but it's effectively what I want to do
  if( myThingMono is empty ) {
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  } else {
    MyThing thing = myThingMono.block(); // I know I can't do this
    switch(thing.status) {
      case A:
        exchange.getResponse().setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
      default: 
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the closest I've gotten in an reactive way

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
  Mono<MyThing> myThingMono = getMyThingMono();
  myThingMono.map(thing -> {
    switch(thing.status) {
      case A: return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
      default: return HttpStatus.OK;
    }        
  })
  .defaultIfEmpty(HttpStatus.OK) // in case myThingMono is empty
  .map(status -> {
    switch(status) {
      case HttpStatus.OK:
        return chain.filter(exchange);
      default:
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(status);
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }        
  })
  .then();
```

The myThingMono wants to return a a `Mono<Object>` but my filter is expecting a `Mono<Void>` so I just jammed a `.then()` into it. I'm sure that's not right.

My code compiles and is reaching the final switch statement and calling the right return statement, but **the request is not reaching my controller**. The webfilter is not forwarding the request correctly. I'm just getting a 200 status back without the handler's result.

What is the right reactive way to do this?

Comment: Place the code from the second map inside the first map and get rid of the `.then()`.

Comment: If everything is in the first map, what happens if `myThingMono` is empty? The 1st map function would be skipped entirely. Also, I think the issue is that the `return` function inside the map doesn't forward the request along. Maybe I don't understand the proposal exactly, so if you could provide some code in an answer, it might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant something like this. I used `.switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty())` to return something if your code does not enter on the first transformation. You can also create a default `Mono.just(new MyThing())`.

Then I used the `flatMap` to place all the logic `switch ...` inside it.

```
enum MyThingEnum { A }

class MyThing { public MyThingEnum status; }

public class Test {
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        Mono<MyThing> myThingMono = getMyThingMono();
        return myThingMono.flatMap(thing -> {
            switch (thing.status) {
                case A:
                    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                    return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
                default:
                    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
                    return chain.filter(exchange);
            }
        })
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty());
    }

    private Mono<MyThing> getMyThingMono() {
        return Mono.just(new MyThing());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. My core issue is that the request flow breaks even though I return the right thing. In you solution, the `switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty())` will definitely break the request flow and prevent the request from reaching the controller, which is the main issue I'm trying to address.

Comment: Actually, this example provided the key to the solution. I was using `.map()` when I should have used `.flatMap()` as in this example.